# Minimal system services(units) and default targets

Tags: boot, gnome, services

Please forgive what may seem like a naive question. I have 30+ years in windows development and IT management, but rarely use Linux. I have an elderly laptop with only 4Gb mem and 4 core @ 2.53Ghz... I originally installed Ubuntu 14ish years ago and it's been a pretty stable box, I have kept up with distro upgrades and from about v19 on up i've noticed a performance and stability hit. currently 21.04 GNOME 3.38.5/X11

I don't use this for much, just app development with VSCode. I don't need any bells or whistles Ie. (web srvr, mail, printing Etc)... So... I have been reading about the boot sequence and going through the targets and how the units get started during boot because I am seeing processes running that I don't need like email and calendar stuff and a huge list of gnome- processes. I'm trying to slim it down to a bare minimum graphical UI.

Looking at the graphical.target it says that multi-user.target is required. Does it have to be? that target is full of dependencies. I only have one user and have no need to switch users. I do not want to reinstall from a minimal-system install CD. My Dev environment is set.

What is the best way to go about reducing my overhead and removing services/devices that I do not absolutely have to have?

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at the graphical.target it says that multi-user.target is required. Does it have to be?

Yes, it is; that is a core functionality of Linux. systemd does it like this:

```
 $  ls -al /lib/systemd/system/runlevel*
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel0.target -> poweroff.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel1.target -> rescue.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel2.target -> multi-user.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel3.target -> multi-user.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel4.target -> multi-user.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target -> graphical.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel6.target -> reboot.target
```

Targets are for GROUPING units and do not take up time in the boot process. And targets are also not relevant for a running system. Nor do those impact performance. services do impact boot up speed; so those add to the time needed to get to the desktop.

> A unit configuration file whose name ends in ".target" encodes
> information about a target unit of systemd, which is used for grouping
> units and as well-known synchronization points during start-up.

- Single user target = rescue.target = rescue mode.
- multi-user.target is the non-graphical part that sets up multi-user and console access. Basically the "server" version
- graphical.target is the desktop.

Without it it would not be Linux :)

---

> I only have one user and have no need to switch users

You have 1 physical person using your machine but there are lots of users on your system ;) But again: this has nothing to do with performance or improving it. All of these are dormant unless used.

---

Now for the main question.

> What is the best way to go about reducing my overhead and removing services/devices that I do not absolutely have to have?

- See `top` on command line for performance, power consumption, cpu usage etc and see if anything stands out. `htop` (needs to be installed) for a nice layout of the same info.
- remove 3rd party drivers or switch on power saving mode for the graphics card
- remove unwanted active services
- clear out orphan libs with `deborphan`

---

To list all active services:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service --state=activ
```

and to stop a service:

```
sudo systemctl disable {service}
```

This WILL keep the software installed though.

> I am seeing processes running that I don't need like email and calendar stuff and a huge list of gnome- processes

Each will have a package name. Remove the software you do not want from "software" and the service will be removed too. Neither of them will improve speed or performance when removed though: when not used the impact on performance is close to zero. All of those are tied with the desktop manager and use the same service; you can not delete that one without deleting the desktop manager.

> with only 4Gb mem and 4 core @ 2.53Ghz

Consider using a version with less requirements; Like Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

> I do not want to reinstall from a minimal-system install CD. My Dev environment is set.

So prepare your setup to withstand a reinstall. Put all alterations you did in a text file so you can execute it after an install. Put all personal files on a separate partition so you can mount it during installation. Use software from source so you can install it on that partition. Put a symlink in your text file to make connect it to a binary in /bin or /usr/bin It is something that takes effort but you only need to do that once.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and very thorough answer. Was there a major change in the desktop/display manager somewhere between v18-20. I don't remember all this gnome stuff. If so can I keep the newer base and use a previous desktop mgr? Would there be any advantage to it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Over the years we went from upstart to systemd as the startup system and started using wayland als manager.  Ubuntu is more resource heavy when using gnome.

Comment: That seems to be what I am running into. Thanks for your time and info